# Can neural networks learn $g(x)$ from $\mathbb{E}[g(X_t)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)p_t(x)dx$

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics

Let $\mathbb{E}_x[g(X_t)]$ be the expected value of a random variable $X_t$ with known probability density $f_t(x)$ then for the continuous case

$$\mathbb{E}[g(X_t)] =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)f_t(x)dx$$

where $g(x)$ or the distribution of $g(x)$ is not known. Hence, one possible pair of the training set in a supervised setting would be $(f_t(x), \mathbb{E}[g(X_t)])$ evaluated at a fixed time $t$. Note that for most distribution the useful bounds are finite.

> Can neural networks learn the function $g(x)$ or its probability distribution?

Reference: [Law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)

I have added a time dependency but the problem is fundamentally the same. Please explain in as much detail as possible. This seems extremely useful if possible.

*images removed

Comment: I'm completely confused. What is $p_t(x)$? You mentioned $f_t(x)$ once but then you never use it... What is that that you observe in each data point? Thanks.

Comment: @stans I apologize I had a typo. You observe the expected value and the distribution of $X_t$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification... My solution is very raw, pretty formal. But I had to post it as a solution, not a comment, because it is too long.

Comment: Is the problem well-defined? There may be infinitely many $g(x)$ that have the same expectation under $f$.

Comment: @MossMurderer We only care to find one of them.

Comment: @Moss Murderer, like almost any problem, this problem may or may not be well-defined depending on the data we are given. For example, in the extreme, if all $f_t(x)$ are delta functions we are recovering the good old "curve fitting" problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. This is an interesting problem......

Formally, speaking, the problem can be solved with neural networks if we discretize the range of the data into M bins. Then every input is a 1-by-M vector. In the intermediate layers, we build the NN in the usual way. The second to last layer has M neurons, each implementing $g(x_i)$. The last layer is non-typical but perfectly allowed. Not only does it connect to the previous layer but also to the input nodes. It takes all of information available and calculates

$
\sum g(x_i)f(x_i)\Delta_i
$

This is a roundabout approach though. I'm sure better approaches exist, after some thinking.

Comment: Can you please explain in your answer what do you mean by 1. "each implementing $g(x)$" as the function is not known, and 2. what is "non-typical"? Any references would also be tremendous

Comment: @Edv Beq, sure $g()$ is unknown. But that is what neural networks do. Each neuron implements something which is unknown, through a combination of prespecified activation functions and unknown weights $W$ in the previous layers. Weights $W$ are estimated from the data using, for example, backpropagation.

Comment: By "non-typical" I mean that, usually, intermediate layers do not connect to the input layer. This is pretty informal.

Comment: Is the input layer fully connected to the second to last layer with weights in between - meaning each input node is connected to all second to last layer nodes with a weight in between? Or, are we just scaling the second to last layer with the corresponding input node?

Comment: Suppose the architecture is: { Inputs ---> Layer $1$ ---> .... ---> Layer $K-1$ ---> Layer $K$ ---> Output }. The inputs are connected to layers $1$ and $K$ only. Generally speaking, they do not have to be connected to any other intermediate layers... Neuron $i$ in layer $K - 1$ implements $g(x_i)$... Weights $W$ entering each neuron in each of the layers $1$ through $K-1$ are unknown and are estimated in the usual way (e.g. backpropagation)... The only neuron in layer $K$ implements $\sum g(x_i) f(x_i) \Delta_i$. The formula is perfectly clear and does not require any extra weights.

Comment: I don't understand sorry. I will draw some pictures later and add them to my question based on your answer.

Comment: @Edv Beq, my last description is quite graphic. You may benefit from improving your knowledge of neural networks a bit. The general theory and how they are built. Hastie, Tibshirani & Friedman is one good reference, even though the authors are somewhat skeptical about neural networks and the reader has to break through that.

Comment: Added images to my question. Can you please tell me if any of the options match the architecture you are describing.

Comment: @Edv Beq Unfortunately, I have to reiterate my previous statement. Pick up a good book and learn NN in a coherent manner... You asked whether there was a NN solution to you specific problem. I said "yes" and stated the solution, clear to everybody with introductory knowledge of NN. You did not start the threat with the request for somebody to explain how NNs work. And even if you did, frankly, addressing your request would be a _disservice_ to you. Clever machine learning areas must be studied in a coherent manner from clever people and clever books, not from a bunch of random dudes on a forum

Comment: in a series of disconnected, scrappy posts… There are reasons why Stanford and MIT structure their programs the way they are. You cannot be somehow more efficient than Stanford or MIT. Here is another valuable set of [lecture notes on neural networks](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/). It is somewhat more advanced than the “Elements of Statistical Learning” book, which I suggested earlier. But it would serve as a nice complement… In my opinion, Crossvalidated threads are for situations when somebody posts a specific problem or needs _direction_. Thanks.